# Phantom/Caperjs User input

Tags: testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I have this script

```
// Prompting user to specify the domain and acting on domain
system.stdout.writeLine('Enter the domain to test - "UAT1","UAT2","RC" or "LIVE" :');
var testingENV = system.stdin.readLine();
```

In addition there are other part of my test script which relies on user input

```
system.stdout.writeLine('Enter your NRIC number :');
var NRICno = system.stdin.readLine();

system.stdout.writeLine('Enter your Mobile number in the follwing format (+6588888888) :');
var MOBno = system.stdin.readLine();
```

Currently the script work fine using sytem.stdin.readline()

I was wondering if i want to create a web interface for testers to test and interact with the script how would i go about doing that .

Comment: Create a nodejs app that uses either [node-phantom](https://www.npmjs.org/package/phantom) or [spookyjs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/spooky) to run phantomjs or casperjs.