# How to click at google search links and follow url

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I try to simulate a google user query search by use following steps.

1. open google search index page and send search query
2. parse link text via css selector
3. and click target otherwise click next page

I can see that engine click the target link but unfortunately if I try to extract the links from the page in line 77, 78 does'n work. any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    waitTimeout: 1000,
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:23.0) Gecko/20130404 Firefox/23.0",
        loadImages: false, // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
        loadPlugins: false,
        verbose: true,
        logLevel: "debug"
    }

});
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.options.waitTimeout = 10000;
var currentPage = 1;
var links = [];


function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("h3.r a");
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        try {
            return (/url\?q=(.*)&sa=U/).exec(e.getAttribute("href"))[1];
        } catch (err) {
            return e.getAttribute("href");
        }
    });
}


var terminate = function() {
    this.echo("that's all, folks.").exit();
};

casper.on("http.status.200", function(resource) {
    this.echo(resource.url + " is OK", "INFO");
});

casper.on("http.status.301", function(resource) {
    this.echo(resource.url + " is permanently redirected", "PARAMETER");
});

casper.on("http.status.302", function(resource) {
    this.echo(resource.url + " is temporarily redirected", "PARAMETER");
});

casper.on("http.status.404", function(resource) {
    this.echo(resource.url + " is not found", "COMMENT");
});

casper.on("http.status.500", function(resource) {
    this.echo(resource.url + " is in error", "ERROR");
});

var processCustomerPage = function() {
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
};


var processPage = function() {
    var url;

    this.wait(10000, function() {
        if (currentPage >= 5 || !this.exists("#pnnext")) {
            return terminate.call(casper);
        }

        currentPage++;
        this.echo("requesting next page: " + currentPage);
        url = this.getCurrentUrl();


        this.wait(3000, function() {
            this.waitForSelector(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='testing - Phantom/Caperjs User input - Stack Overflow']"), function() {
                this.click(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='testing - Phantom/Caperjs User input - Stack Overflow']"));
                this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());

                                                links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
                        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
                        this.echo(' [+] ' + links.join("\n - "));

                this.reload(function() {
                    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
                });

                this.echo("loaded again");
                this.echo(this.getTitle());
                return terminate.call(casper);

            });


            return terminate.call(casper);
        });

        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());

        this.thenClick("#pnnext").then(function() {

            this.waitFor(function() {
                return url !== this.getCurrentUrl();
            }, processPage, terminate);
        });
    });
};

casper.start("http://google.de/", function() {
    this.fill('form[action="/search"]', {
        q: 'casperjs'
    }, true);
});

casper.waitForSelector('#pnnext', processPage, terminate);

casper.run();
```

Comment: *"does'n work"* is not a good problem description. What did you expect and what did you get in return? Have you tried to save a screenshot to see if you're on the correct page?

Comment: I want to handle the HTML content of the target link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217970/phantom-caperjs-user-input after click the selectXPath